# Подскажите, как правильно реализовать функцию formatDistanceToNow из библиотеки date-fns?

Tags: reactjs, date-fns

Нужно, чтобы время показывало от момента создания задачи до настоящего времени, с использованием функции  formatDistanceToNow - "created 5 minutes ago"
если нужна доп информация, скину все, что нужно

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const createDate = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00'); // тут дата создания
formatDistance(createDate, currentDate); // вернет сколько прошло времени между первой и второй датой, в таком формате "3 days ago"
```